# How to conditional format in Google Sheets based on a external resource

Tags: conditional-formatting, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that has a value of a stock I bought in the past.  The page was stark with just white cells and black text.  So I decided to brighten it up with some colour.

One thing I want to do is show if the current value is below or above the purchased value for that date.

So for instance: I bought **T** on the **08/03/2021** at **$22.29** per share.  I would like to have the  price be coloured red if value is below that or green if the current value is above that price.

With conditional formatting I can do this on a custom rule `=GOOGLEFINANCE(C2, "closeyest") < D2` where C2 is the ticker symbol (T) and D2 is the price I paid per share. For the green I just swap the `<` for a `>`.

However this is locked to the values in C2/D2 - making the conditional format apply to a range only compares against the values in C2/D2. I could get 2 conditional formats per cell but with nearly 700 cells to update it will take a very long time.

How do I get the C2/D2 to update with the row value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of referencing **C2**, you need to reference **$C2**.

There are two Conditional formatting rules. Each contains a unique custom formula - one each for the value greater/less than than your buy price.

- `=googlefinance($A5,"closeyest")>B5` - yesterday's price is higher than your buy price
- `=googlefinance($A5,"closeyest")<B5` - yesterday's price is less than your buy price.

The data in Column C is provided for information. It is NOT used in the forula or conditional formating.

---

[image: snapshot]